# How to plot multiple functions in a graph with different colors?

Tags: plotting, matrix, list-manipulation

I have a general {i,x,y} dimensional matrix, and I want to plot all "i" {x,y} matrices in one graph. How can I do it in a way that I can still distinguish each "i"th curve from the other (I mean creating curves with different colors using plot).

This a example of a code I written, but since I used table to create a loop I couldn't distinguish the curves:

```
a = Table[Random[], {i, 1, 4}, {x, 1, 6}, {y, 1, 5}];

Show[Table[
aFxn = ListInterpolation[(Chop[a[[i + 1]]] - Chop[a[[i]]])];
Table[aFxn[\[Theta], \[Phi]], {\[Theta], 1, 6}, {\[Phi], 1, 5}];
Plot[Abs[aFxn[3, \[Phi]]], {\[Phi], 1, 5}, 
PlotLegends -> {Subscript[Ne, i]}, PlotRange -> All, 
AxesLabel -> {Ne, spinupcoefficient}], {i, 1, 3}]]
```

My real matrices have higher dimensions, so I can not use Plot[{},{},{},..] to create the different colors.

I would be thankful if somebody could help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
curves = Table[
   aFxn = ListInterpolation[(Chop[a[[i + 1]]] - Chop[a[[i]]])];
   Abs[aFxn[3, ϕ]]
   , {i, 1, 3}];

Plot[curves, {ϕ, 1, 5}, 
 PlotLegends -> Table[Subscript[Ne, i], {i, 1, 3}]]
```

[image]

Another option:

```
curve[i_] :=
 ListInterpolation[(Chop[a[[i + 1]]] - Chop[a[[i]]])]

Plot[Evaluate@Table[Abs[curve[i][3, ϕ]], {i, 1, 3}], {ϕ, 1, 5}, 
 PlotLegends -> Table[Subscript[Ne, i], {i, 1, 3}]]
```

> same image

Comment: Thank you, I guess that's what I want

Comment: How to do I show the plotlegends for different colors corresponding to different "i"s?

Comment: I want sth like   PlotLegends -> {Subscript[Ne, i]} , corresponding to each i

Comment: adding plot legend after {\[Phi], 1, 
  5} doesn't work for me

Comment: @DelaramNematollahi Updated answer to include PlotLegends.

Comment: Thank you so much